# ggplot- revenue showing as lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot revenue against period end date using ggplot. I am getting vertical lines on the period end date when I would expect to get lines that connect.

It looks as though the revenue is not summing on period end date (there are multiple values for revenue in a period in the data). Revenue is set to an integer and period end date is *POSIXct*. How can I fix this?

```
ggplot(data = Rawdata, aes(x =PeriodEndDate,y = Revenue)) +
  geom_line(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2)+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: You probably aren't feeding `ggplot` the data in the correct format.  Finish any data analysis before you plot it.  Here, this is likely caused by many points for each date which would cause your issue. Or you might be forgetting to add a grouping.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. How would I add a grouping? can you provide an example?

Comment: It's easier if you provide the example - could you post a few rows of data? `dput` is best because it is copy/pasteable and preserves the class and structure information. `dput(Rawdata[1:10, ])` would give us the first 10 rows, but choose another small subset if you think it better illustrates your data. Once you give us some example input, we can show code that would work on it.

Comment: Gregor's comment above is very accurate.  We need some data provided by you to really be able to help.